# How can I add a tab in jquery-ui Tabs and then select it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I understand how to add a jquery-ui tab, and I understand how to select a tab by index number, but how can I both add a tab and then select it?

For example, in the following demo you can add a tab, but then you have to click on it for it to be displayed:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation

I'm on jquery 1.4.2 and jquery-ui 1.8rc3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have added the tab like the example just use the [select method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select).  You will have to know the index of the tab you just added.  If you just added it to the end you can use the [length method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-length), if not then you already know the index of the tab because you defined it when you added it.

Comment: Thanks.  The length method is what I needed to know about.  For future reference, the syntax I needed is `$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected', 'length');`.

Answer (score 3):

The 'length' and 'selected' options has been deprecated and removed now, so to select the last
tab (which is the one that has just been added) use

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', -1);
```

This works because if you specify negative values, the tabs are counted from the end backwards starting at -1.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use this:

```
      var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
            add: function(event, ui) {
                $tabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
            }
        });
```

Docs here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...immediately_select_a_just_added_tab

However, I'm having a problem where this bit of code only works after the first one that I add... ie: doesn't work for the first one. Can't figure that out...