# how to load contents in each tab one by one in jquery tabs

Tags: jquery

I have loaded items in jquery tabs. After page loading, i want to show contents of each tab one by one. First I want to show first tab and then contents of the first tab. After that I want to show second tab and then contents of the second tab and so on. How to do that?

Comment: It would better, You post your Codes. And, What mean by **One By One**?

Comment: Refer http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @Subedi Second tab items are loaded prior to first tab items. that is why I told one by one. My requirement is after first tab items completely loaded then only second tab items must be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How can I add a tab in jquery-ui Tabs and then select it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440451/how-can-i-add-a-tab-in-jquery-ui-tabs-and-then-select-it).  Just do it for each new tab...